# Why does my code delete the first row from database

Tags: php

i need your help. I have my delete all records button, when i delete all records it works fine until when i try to add records after the delete all, the first record will be deleted when i try to add the second record. i think the problem is because i never close my query after the delete all records.. i dont the exact syntax that can be used in my codes. please help me guys.
here is my code for delete all:

```
<?php
include_once 'connection.php';
$fname = $lname = $username = $phone = $email = $cemail = "";
$act="";
$txtid = 0;
if(isset($_GET['act'])){
    $act=$_GET['act'];

    if($act=='delete'){
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $sql="delete from tbl_admin where id = $id";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
        if($result){
        }
    }

    if($act=='deleteall'){
        $sql="delete from tbl_admin";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
    }


    if($act=='edit'){
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $sql="select * from tbl_admin where id = $id";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $txtid = $row['id'];
            $fname = $row['fname'];
            $lname = $row['lname'];
            $username = $row['username'];
            $phone = $row['mobileNo'];
            $email = $row['email'];
        }

    }

    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        // fname validate
        if(empty($_POST["fname"])){
            echo '<script> alert("first name is empty!"); </script>';
        }else{
            $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
            // lname validate
            if(empty($_POST["lname"])){
                echo '<script> alert("last name is empty!"); </script>';
            }else{
                $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
                //username
                if(empty($_POST["username"])){
                    echo '<script> alert("username is empty!"); </script>';
                }else{
                    $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
                    //phone
                    if(empty($_POST["phone"])){
                        echo '<script> alert("mobile number is empty!!"); </script>';
                    }else{
                        $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
                        //email
                        if(empty($_POST["email"])){
                            echo '<script> alert("email is empty!"); </script>';
                        }else{
                            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
                            //cemail
                            if(empty($_POST["cemail"])){
                                echo '<script> alert("confirm email is empty!"); </script>';
                            }else{
                                $cemail = test_input($_POST["cemail"]);
                                if($email != $cemail){
                                    echo '<script> alert("Confirm Email!"); </script>';
                                }else{
                                    $sql= "insert into tbl_admin(fname,lname,username,password,mobileNo,email,add_date) values('$fname','$lname','$username','123abc','$phone','$email',NOW())";
                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
                                    if($result){
                                        echo '<script> alert("Successfully add admin user."); </script>';
                                        $fname = $lname = $username = $phone = $email = $cemail = "";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
        if(empty($txtid)){
            echo '<script>
                    alert("Select record to Update!");
                </script>';
        }else{
            echo '<script>
                    alert("you can update record..");
                </script>';
                $fname = $lname = $username = $phone = $email = $cemail = "";

        }
    }

    function test_input($data){
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: No it will be because you are not testing when the delete should be done in your code properly. **show all the code** Connections are closed automatically when a script terminates

Comment: thanks for quick response sir, what do mean about "not testing when the delete should be done"? can you please elaborate it through codes? thanks

Comment: I could but only if you post more of your code. **edit your question** dont post in comments

Comment: what specific codes you need men?

Comment: Dont be specific. **show it all**

Comment: i add my add transaction.. i hope you could help me men..

Comment: Is that the COMPLETE script?

Comment: see above all my script men...

Comment: I'm not sure if w3schools is the best source to learn advanced stuff. Here's a code that I would suggest to use, just to validate the data https://3v4l.org/FDsC2

Comment: thanks @Richard for the reference, i will try it after i solve my problem regarding in my post.

Comment: have you heard of sql injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ALL your code exists inside this if statement

```
if(isset($_GET['act'])){
```

Then we have to assume that `$_GET['act']` **is always set to something**

Because `$_GET['act']` is always set to something then the DELETE code is getting run **ALWAYS**. Either its `delete` or `deleteall`

The code that rebuilds your web page is still missing, but basically you need to organise your code more logically, and also make sure that `$_GET['act']` is only set when **you actually want to do a delete**, which would probably mean changing the HTML so it is not being left set.

Comment: thank you @RiggsFolly, you enlighten me with that. I'm not so sure how to organize my delete and delete all the same in my add.. can please help me how? many thanks man.

Comment: There is still too much of your code (HTML) missing. Also, you would be better off doing it yourself, that is the way to improve your abilities

Comment: thank you for your advice men, can you give references to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the methods are the same as it was in mysql (without i)

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php

with non-object-oriented way it would be

```
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Comment: Although this is unlikely to have anything to do with the OP's actual problem

Comment: not error actually, but when i try to add again after the delete all records, the first record will be deleted if i add another records.